# What is wrong with this foreach statement?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```
<?php
include ('config.php');
$connection = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
$db = mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $connection);
$machinename = $_POST['machinename'];
$safemachinename = mysql_real_escape_string($machinename);
$query = mysql_query("delete from Notification where machinename=$safemachinename", $connection);
$query = mysql_query("delete from Keystrokes where machinename=$safemachinename", $connection);
$query = mysql_query("delete from Clipboard where machinename=$safemachinename", $connection);
$query = mysql_query("delete from Passwords where machinename=$safemachinename", $connection);
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox){
    $query = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE $checkbox", $connection);
}
?>
```

I'm getting the error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). Is it because I'm testing without checking any of the checkboxes?

Does this look correct?

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox){
    $query = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE $checkbox", $connection);
}
}
```

Here is the checkboxes

```
<form method="post" name="checkDelete" id="checkDelete" action="deletelogs.php">
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="Notifications"/> Notifications</label><br>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="Keystrokes"/> Keystrokes</label><br>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="Passwords"/> Passwords</label><br>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="Clipboard"/> Clipboard Records</label><br><br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Logs</button>
</form>
```

Basically you are selecting with checkboxes what tables you want to delete. This is for a client administration program.

Alright so far so good. This doesn't seem to be deleting anything:

```
<form method="post" name="formdelete" id="formdelete" action="deletelogs.php">
<div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Delete all logs where computer name is</label><input class="form-control" width = "200px" placeholder="Please input machine name here..." /><br>
<br>
<center><input type="submit" name="btnDelete" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete now"></center>
</form>

$machinename = $_POST['machinename'];
$safemachinename = mysql_real_escape_string($machinename);
$query = mysql_query("delete from Notification where machinename=$safemachinename", $connection);
$query = mysql_query("delete from Keystrokes where machinename=$safemachinename", $connection);
$query = mysql_query("delete from Clipboard where machinename=$safemachinename", $connection);
$query = mysql_query("delete from Passwords where machinename=$safemachinename", $connection);
```

Comment: yes thats the reason, when you don't check any boxes, `$_POST['checkbox']` will be undefined basically, and don't continue using this old API anymore as you are open to SQL injections, use PDO with prepared statements instead. http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: You don't appear to have any form inputs named `machinename` or `checkbox`

Comment: Good luck protecting those `TRUNCATE TABLE` queries from hosing your entire DB.

Comment: `<form method="post" name="machinename" value="machinename" id="formdelete" action="deletelogs.php">
<div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Delete all logs where computer name is</label><input class="form-control" width = "200px" placeholder="Please input machine name here..." /><br>
<br>
<center><input type="submit" name="btnDelete" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete now"></center>
</form>` Does that look correct for the input named machinename?

Comment: Broken Record Warning: Lose Mysql_query

Answer (score 1):

You have error in html part. use like this

```
<form method="post" name="checkDelete" id="checkDelete" action="">
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Notifications"/> Notifications</label><br>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Keystrokes"/> Keystrokes</label><br>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Passwords"/> Passwords</label><br>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Clipboard"/> Clipboard Records</label><br><br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Logs</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I'd name them `checkbox[]` if OP wants to use the values in a `foreach` loop but then again, I'd never blindly pass table names in from user-land

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you like by doing:

```
if(isset($_POST['info'])){
      foreach($_POST['info'] as $checkbox){
      if(isset(checkbox)){
          $query = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE $checkbox", $connection);
     }
   }
}

<form method="post" name="checkDelete" id="checkDelete" action="deletelogs.php">
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="info[]" value="Notifications"/> Notifications</label><br>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="info[]" value="Keystrokes"/> Keystrokes</label><br>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="info[]" value="Passwords"/> Passwords</label><br>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="info[]" value="Clipboard"/> Clipboard Records</label><br><br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Logs</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm now getting another error. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'. Copy pasted exactly like it is. No extra {.

Comment: Sorry about that. i forget the extra `)`. The answer is fixed @Ben

Comment: It's not deleting because there is a problem with the SQL statement. For that, you'll want to ask a new question @Ben

Answer (score 0):

That would be part of it. By default, PHP's $_POST array is one level deep, so while you are guaranteed to be able to iterate over $_POST, $_POST['checkbox'] may be an array (if your input names are checkbox[0], checkbox[foo], etc.), a string, or unset.

So you'll need to do an isset() && is_array() before your foreach to make sure that your foreach doesn't fail.

Additionally, make sure that you have the "value" attribute set for each of your checkboxes. Otherwise you'll be truncating "on" rather than the table you're expecting.

Comment: Oh do I need to use value not name?

Comment: You'll need to use both. For example, checking <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="something" /> and submitting the form would put "something" in $_POST['checkbox']. If you want to have multiple checkboxes in a single $_POST key, you can do <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[foo]" value="another thing" /> and you'll end up with $_POST['checkbox']['foo'] being set to "another thing" when it's checked. Does that clear things up?

Comment: Alright it is working. I have an issue with an earlier part of my code however. `$machinename = $_POST['machinename'];
$safemachinename = mysql_real_escape_string($machinename);
$query = mysql_query("delete from Notification where machinename=$safemachinename", $connection);` That part of it (look at OP for cleaner version). It doesn't seem to be deleting anything.

Comment: Your input needs to have an attribute of name="machinename" to work. Also, as others have said, truncating random tables without validating input is a Very Bad Thing(tm), because you can't trust users to just use whatever checkboxes you put on your page.